# csv file convert integer to float with applescript

Tags: javascript, csv, integer, applescript

I am downloading historic stock quotes from Yahoo Finance as a csv file. However, one column (trade volume) is an integer value and when reading it into MaxMSp I am getting nonsensical values. Therfore, I would like to convert that specific column to floating point values
Example instead of 18999000 I would like a point added at the end so you get 18999000. I was wondering if this is possible using Applescript so I can bypass using Excell or Numbers.

Comment: Can you add a link to an example of the data file on Yahoo? Also how are you reading it into Max, that could be the issue too. The more info you can give the more likely you'll get an answer

Comment: Link to historical data: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=BAC&a=04&b=29&c=2013&d=01&e=18&f=2014&g=d You can download the dataset as a csvfile
As you can see, the 6th column contains very large integers. MaxMSP cannot handle those values as integers. When I turn them into floats by adding .0 at the end (for example 189 becomes 189.0) it seems to work. I can ask the user to use Excel to convert the column manually but it would be better if there would be a script to do that. If the integer--> float conversion would be impossible I would settle for a division by 1000 and state that in the manual.

Comment: Maybe there's a way when you read the csv into max to do the conversion to float. This would save your users having to do any extra steps.

Comment: I got it almost right. I only need to add an index number in front of every line. Here is the code I have until now: 

function import(filename)
{
 var f = new File(filename);
 
 if (f.open) {
  outlet(0, "clear");
  
  while (f.position < f.eof) {
  
   var str = f.readline(); 
   var a = str.split(","); // conver strings to array (elements are delimited by a coma)
   a[5] /= 1000; // uncomment to devide the 6th column by 1000
   outlet(0, "store", a); // store in the coll
  }
  f.close();
 } else {
  error("couldn't find the file ("+ filename +")\n");
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

To convert a number to a float, you can multiply by 1.0

```
"5" * 1.0
--> 5.0
```

If you just need a decimal point at the end, you can concatenate it

```
"5" & "."
--> "5."
```